# x11vnc window manager

Tags: x11, window-manager, vnc

I am using `x11vnc` and started it so it created the X server by itself like this:

```
x11vnc -localhost -rfbauth -create /root/.vnc/passwd
```

But the VNC session created, does not have a window manager, just an `xterm` in the upper left corner. How can I specify one?

By the way, is there a way to automatically stop the X-Server if I disconnect from `x11vnc`, so this essentially works as `X` on demand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the windowmanager after starting the x11 server.

For example, my batch to start xvnc:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0
/usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -ac -auth "/root/.Xauthority" -geometry "1200x700" -depth 8 -rfbwait 120000 -rfbauth /root/.vnc/passwd 2> /root/.vnc/ServerDaemon.log &
/bin/sleep 10
/usr/bin/fvwm 2> /root/.vnc/fvwm.log &
```

I redirect errors in log files and use the sleep command, so that Xvnc has surely initialiesed itself, bevor starting the fvwm window manager.
But there should be no problem to start any other windowmanager.

For automatically stop the x11 server, I don't know.